# How does lending / leasing in NXT work? What are some use case scenarios?

Tags: nxt

Since you can lend / lease you nxt to another account.

What are the pros/cons of this nxt lending feature?

What are some use case scenarios?

Answer (score 1):

Leasing gives the other account your forging power, without giving them the ability to spend your coins. The two main use cases are:

- To lease to a forging pool run by someone else. This avoids the need for you to run a server 24/7, and the pool should forge more often, smoothing out the peaks and troughs in forging income.
- To lease to a forging node run by yourself, but on a machine you don't trust; for example a cloud service. You keep your balance on a secure machine and lease it to the insecure one.